# Making own buttons in tinymce, using bbcode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinymce, bbcode

rails gem in my rails app. i use it with bbcode and as parser i use bbcodeizer.

bbcodeizer allows me to define own bbcode tags.
tinymce allows me to add own buttons.

if i want to add a button, how do i make it work in the wysiwyg part of tinymce editor?

```
ed.addButton('mybutton2', {
                    title : 'My button2',
                    image : 'img/example.gif',
                    onclick : function() {
                        // Add you own code to execute something on click
                        ed.focus();
                            ed.selection.setContent("[center]" + ed.selection.getContent() + '[/center]');
                    }
                });
```

with that, i get my tinymce to add a [center]text[/center] around my text, in this way it is visible in my editor and saved in the database.

but how do i make it become visble in the editor like this

```
<p style="text-align">text</p>
```

(without html tags showing, but using them for wysiwyg) and saving [center]text[/center] in my database?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to insert `<p style="text-align">text</p>` with '<' and '>' as entities ('`& gt;`' and '`& lt;`' (remove space)).
when saving your content to the database you will need to replace your entities with '`[center]`' and '`[/center]`'. You may use the onSave event for that.

Comment: u may got me wrong. i found out, that    ed.selection.setContent('<p style="text-align;">' + ed.selection.getContent() + '</p>'); was what i needed for getting the text centered in the editor text area. but there is a weird problem now. it only saves: <p style="text-align:center;">text    without the </p> in the end. furthermore i dont get onSave saving [center]text[/center]

Comment: btw if i use div tag, it saves div text div, but with p it doesnt save the 2nd p?

Comment: it should save the 2nd p. maybe you got a type on the way to the db?